# Returning a value from Javascript to C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I have tried searching for answers but nothing seems to have worked thus far. I have a GUI application that I am building for WinAPI, and I want to use a Javascript function that will check on the Youtube API for certain videos and such, but I haven't been able to call on any of the functions in Javascript.

The farthest I've seemed to be able to get is to add an HTML file to the external dependencies(.rc), and then the Javasctipt file from there, but I can't seem to be able to just call on the function.

Is there a better way of doing this than trying to interop Javasctipt and C++, or am I just going about calling the function wrong?

```
/* Pseudocode */

Javascript.js
void callAPI()
{
... Call on the Youtube API, check if there are new videos i'd like...
return boolIfUpdatedOrNot;
}



Source.cpp
... Some includes and such ...


WindowProc and such
{
Case Something:
... Call on the Javascript function ...
... Do something if returned true ...
... or return 0 if false ...
}
```

Comment: You could use the V8 engine but I rather advice you to send request to the youtube api by your own

Comment: While it's possible to interop JavaScript and C++ e.g. via Windows Script Host automation (you can define a COM server in JavaScript), I would rather look for libraries that help do the underlying network stuff from C++. Perhaps https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/client-libraries (which is where I ended up following links)

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I've seen people use the V8 engine, but I've not yet explored that. Do you also mean for me to send a request by my own, to just go and click on the page myself? This is more just experimenting with interoperability.

Comment: No with sending the request by your own I mean to construct a HTTP request and send it over the wire, receiving the repsonse and parsing it. Thats much better than to take a detour over js

Comment: You don't need JavaScript at all to access the YouTube API. Any GET request will do, and it's dead easy to generate GET requests from Windows API. Besides, calling executable code from JavaScript is nigh to impossible, for obvious security reasons. You would have to build a browser plugin or equivalent techniques for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need Javascript to get the videos? If you don't need to authenticate, there is a simple data API that will return up to 50 videos specified by certain parameters such as playlist ID or search term. You can get the results in JSON or XML by using a simple HTTP GET request. I'm not familiar with doing this in WINAPI, but you could probably start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384110(v=vs.85).aspx

A simple example that will get the 10 most recent uploads from a channel with CHANNEL_NAME:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNEL_NAME/uploads?max-results=10`

To get this in JSON:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNEL_NAME/uploads?v=2&max-results=10&alt=jsonc`

You have to use the second version of the API to get it in JSON (hence the v=2 parameter). XML will probably be easier to parse in native C++ though, depending on whether you want to work with another library.

For more: https://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html